# Xcode memory addresses were in hex but now are in decimal. How do I change back to hex?

Tags: xcode

Using Xcode 4.2.  When viewing memory in the memory browser, the memory addresses in the leftmost column (called "Line Numbers" in the Editor menu) are showing up as decimal numbers.  Earlier today, they were in hex.  I much prefer hex but I can't figure out how to change the format from decimal back to hex.

The individual variables, shown in the Variables View, have addresses in hex.  The contents of memory are also shown in hex.

Edit:
Screenshot: The red rectangle is around the decimal addresses.  I have since found that clicking anywhere in the column with the red rect toggles between hex and decimal addresses.

Thx to CocoaFu for helping me figure this out. 
[image: http://imgur.com/8D4xg].

Comment: If you get an answer that works for you then accept it and you will get reputation points.  It also shows respect for the person who answered.

Comment: Thx, CocoaFu. Your screenshot is how my memory browser looked *before*.  Now, there is one difference.  On the first line of memory contents, instead of showing 0x100114160 to the left of the first row showing "03 00 00 00...", my memory browser would show 4296098144(same address in decimal).  My browser shows the hex value everywhere else in the window.  Other than that, my memory browser looks just like yours.  I called that left column "Line Numbers" cuz that's how it's named in the Editor menu when a memory browser is up.  Editor menu lets Show/Hide different parts of the memory browser.

Comment: @CocoaFu. Just making sure you're notified of my comment.

Comment: @CocoaFu.  Emailed a screenshot to Zaph.

Comment: @CocoaFu. Stumbled on the fix. Clicking on the "Line Numbers" column toggles the addresses between hex and decimal.  Tried to answer my own question, but...  No rep. Sigh. ;)

Comment: Great find, I did not notice that.

Comment: @CocoaFu. Hey, thanks for your help so far. One more change needed to the screenshot in your answer. Clicking the "IC Image" reveals a pop-up menu of past target addresses. To toggle the address base between hex and decimal, you click anywhere in the grey column of addresses to the left of the memory contents area. In your screenshot, it's the column with 100114160 at the top and 100114220 at the bottom.  I'll accept your answer, with thanks, if you just move that red rect over to the right spot. Thanks again. I'd do this myself if I could. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how you are trying but the first clue is "Line Numbers" that you are not viewing memory.  I created:

```
int *a = malloc(500);
a[0] = 3;
```

right (control) clicked on the "a" in the locals variable display, selected

```
View Memory of "*a"
```

Click in the red rect to change between different address bases (decimal/hexadecimal)--thanks to @onquest

[image]